# How to define the width of apex:pageBlockTable columns?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two tables, I can change the 'width' in the first table but I am having some problems using width in the second tables, I tried adding `columns="9" columnsWidth="20%,10%,10%,10%",10%",10%",10%",10%",10%" width="100%"` to the `pageBlockTable`. Also, I used 'px' instead of '%', and also, I tried to add the width to every column but it doesn't work.

If anyone has an advice or can share a different approach, I will really appreciate it. Thank you

```html
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="1stTable" >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!NRProducts__c}" var="o"  align="center"columnsWidth="40%,20%,20%,20%" width="100%"> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection  >
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
</apex:pageBlockTable>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="2ndTable" >
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!NRProducts__c}" var="o"  align="center"      rowClasses="odd,even" CELLSPACING="30" CELLPADDING="0"  >        

            <apex:column headerValue="Active?"> 
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!o.Active__c}"/>
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column headerValue="noReorder"> 
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!o.noReorder__c}"/>
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column headerValue="Name"> 
                <apex:outputLink value="http://www.domain.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%keywords={!o.Search_Text__c}" target="_blank">{!o.Search_Text__c}</apex:outputLink> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Search_Text__c}" rendered="{!EditMode}" />
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column headerValue="ASIN"> 
                <apex:outputLink value="http://www.domain.com/{!o.ASIN__c}" target="_blank">{!o.ASIN__c}</apex:outputLink>
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.ASIN__c}" rendered="{!EditMode}" /> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column headerValue="FNSKU"> 
                <apex:outputField value="{!o.FNSKU__c}" rendered="{!NOT(EditMode)}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.FNSKU__c}" rendered="{!EditMode}" />
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column headerValue="UPC"> 
                <apex:outputLink value="http://www.domain.com/s?url=search-alias={!o.UPC__c}" target="_blank">{!o.UPC__c}</apex:outputLink>           
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.UPC__c}" rendered="{!EditMode}" />
            </apex:column>               
            <apex:column headerValue="Model No."> 
                <apex:outputField value="{!o.Model_Number__c}" rendered="{!NOT(EditMode)}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.Model_Number__c}" rendered="{!EditMode}" /> 
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Manufactor No."> 
                <apex:outputField value="{!o.ManufacturerNo__c}" rendered="{!NOT(EditMode)}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.ManufacturerNo__c}" rendered="{!EditMode}" /> 
            </apex:column>           
            <apex:column headerValue="Warehouse Code"> 
                <apex:outputField value="{!o.WarehouseCode__c}" rendered="{!NOT(EditMode)}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!o.WarehouseCode__c}" rendered="{!EditMode}" /> 
            </apex:column> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
<apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This page:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! null }" var="r" columnsWidth="60%,20%,10%,10%">
            <apex:column headerValue="Name1">
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name2">
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name3"> 
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name4"> 
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

emits output that looks correct in Chrome (columns of varying widths) and has this in the HTML it generates:

```
<table class="list " id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <colgroup span="4"><col width="60%"><col width="20%"><col width="10%"><col width="10%"></colgroup>
    <thead...
```

The columnsWidth text you posted in your question had extra quotes in it. I suggest you check the HTML generated by your code and compare it with the above.

The above also works with more than one table.

**PS** I've just formatted your posted Visualforce so it all shows up and it does contain spurious `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` elements that you should remove.

Comment: Keith, one question, the sum of the width & has to be 100%?

Comment: @Carlos You are welcome. I'm afraid I don't know what happens when they don't sum to 100% - you could try that out on a test page

Comment: The widths don't have to add to 100; the table will format but perhaps not with widths as you intended