# Vertically align two pageBlocks

Tags: visualforce, pageblock

I've got minor annoyance: I'm rendering two pageBlocks one after another, but they end up not aligning correctly.

Here's the code:

```
<apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Populates all fields with the same value" mode="edit" id="masspgblck" helpTitle="hello">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Electricity_Meter__c}" var="mult" >
               <apex:column value="{!mult.Name}"/>                  
                <apex:column value="{!mult.Site_name__c}"/>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Local Network Folder" value="{!mult.Account__r.Local_Network_Folder__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!mult.AUTO_AFF_Info_as_Account__c}"/>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Override AFF 1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!mult.Override_AFF_1__c}">
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="muselected"/>
                 </apex:inputField>
                </apex:column>   
                <apex:column headerValue="Override AFF 1 Profit % Split">
                <apex:inputField value="{!mult.Override_AFF_1_Profit_Split__c}">
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="muselected"/>
                 </apex:inputField>
                </apex:column>   
         </apex:pageBlockTable> 
         </apex:pageBlock>  
    <apex:pageblock title="Logging" id="muselected">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >        
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>            
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="elecM">                 
                <apex:column value="{!elecM.Name}"/>                   
                <apex:column value="{!elecM.Site_name__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!elecM.Account__r.Local_Network_Folder__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!elecM.AUTO_AFF_Info_as_Account__c}"/>                       
                <apex:column headerValue="Override AFF 1" footerValue="Override AFF 1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!elecM.Override_AFF_1__c}"/>
                </apex:column>   
                <apex:column headerValue="Override AFF 1 Profit % Split" footerValue="Override AFF 1 Profit % Split">
                <apex:inputField value="{!elecM.Override_AFF_1_Profit_Split__c}"/>
                </apex:column>   
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>
```

Which comes out as:

[image: Two pageBlocks misaligned]

As you can see second table starts with a little offset. Anyone got an idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Do they line up if you remove the pageblock buttons from the second one? Just thinking out loud as that seems to be the only difference between the two. Your other potential issue will be the width of the columns where there is data.It also looks like there is css differences between the two. Are you applying anything to the first page block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to play with **columns** and **columnsWidth** into your apex:pageBlockTable's. If you define the same widths in each table they should be align correctly. Similar post : [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29994/how-to-define-the-width-of-apexpageblocktable-columns)

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!table1}" var="item" columns="6" columnsWidth="100px,80px,40px,40px,40px,40px">
   ...
</apex:pageBlockTable>

 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!table2}" var="item" columns="6" columnsWidth="100px,80px,40px,40px,40px,40px">
   ...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Curious, do these column widths prevent the small indentation of the overall table as seen in the OP results?

Comment: Wow, that is probably the quickest fix I've ever made. Solved by simply adding `columnsWidth="140px"` to first PageBlockTable which indents first column, like this:`<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Electricity_Meter__c}" var="mult" columnsWidth="140px">` many thanks!

Comment: Good one even easier that what I said.